# Docker Compose merge arrays for YAML aliases and anchors

Tags: docker, yaml

I have the following broken docker-compose file

```yaml
version: '3.4'

x-vols1: &vols-1
    - /home/:/home/

x-vols2: &vols-2
    - /tmp/:/tmp/

services:
    app1:
        container_name: app1
        image: app1
        volumes:
            <<: *vols-1
    app2:
        container_name: app2
        image: app2
        volumes:
            <<: *vols-1
            <<: *vols-2
```

This fails with the following error

```sh
$ docker-compose -f test.yaml config
ERROR: yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: while constructing a mapping
  in "./test.yaml", line 14, column 13
expected a mapping for merging, but found scalar
  in "./test.yaml", line 4, column 7
```

**Question 1:** How can I merge arrays in `docker-compose`? The syntax that I am trying to use is the one for merging dicts

**Question 2:** If there is no way to merge arrays, is there a workaround?

Use case: I have multiple services, some of them map some volumes, others map other volumes, others map all volumes. I would like to not repeat myself.

Thank you!

Comment: I would advise you to follow the KISS principle and not start programming in configuration files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired behavior can be achieved by using multiple `docker-compose` files, one for each volume. Note that the anchors and aliases are not required, but keeping them in to align with the question.

`base.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
    app1:
        container_name: app1
        image: app1
    app2:
        container_name: app2
        image: app2
```

`vol1.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.4'

x-vols1: &vols-1
    volumes:
        - /home/:/home/

services:
    app1:
        container_name: app1
        image: app1
        <<: *vols-1
    app2:
        container_name: app2
        image: app2
        <<: *vols-1
```

`vol2.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.4'

x-vols2: &vols-2
    volumes:
        - /tmp/:/tmp/

services:
    app2:
        container_name: app2
        image: app2
        <<: *vols-2
```

Verify as

```sh
$ docker-compose -f base.yaml -f vol1.yaml -f vol2.yaml config
```

Result

```yaml
services:
  app1:
    container_name: app1
    image: app1
    volumes:
    - /home:/home:rw
  app2:
    container_name: app2
    image: app2
    volumes:
    - /home:/home:rw
    - /tmp:/tmp:rw
version: '3.4'
```

Additional documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Comment: In this case you've changed from merging arrays to merging a mapping. Multiple compose files shouldn't be needed for that.

Comment: That is only partially true. The mappings are merged recursively and eventually the arrays themselves are merged, which answers the question.

Comment: You still need multiple compose files, otherwise, merging the mappings alone (using yaml alone) will overwrite the values.

Comment: Indeed. Looks like compose is doing better with merging than yaml. If you start getting too complicated, it may be worth looking at some templating tools like gomplate and jsonnet.

Answer (score 8):

The Yaml merge syntax is for merging mappings, not for arrays. For more on that, see [this issue](https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/35). However, if you are just adding single volumes, you don't need to merge anything. Just insert the alias as an array entry:

```
version: '3.4'

x-vols1: &vols-1
    "/home/:/home/"

x-vols2: &vols-2
    "/tmp/:/tmp/"

services:
    app1:
        container_name: app1
        image: app1
        volumes:
            - *vols-1
    app2:
        container_name: app2
        image: app2
        volumes:
            - *vols-1
            - *vols-2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping that docker-compose added some support for array merging (for `<:`) as the issue suggests.

My use case is having multiple elements in each of the variables unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3):

This is a slight variation on the currently [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61178760/2089675) answer, which doesn't require you to change your *docker-compose* command line to include other files:

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
    app1:
        container_name: app1
        image: app1
        extends:
            file: common-volumes.yml
            service: app1
    app2:
        container_name: app2
        image: app2
        extends:
            file: common-volumes.yml
            service: app2
        volumes:
            - /tmp/:/tmp/
```

#### common-volumes.yml

```yaml
x-vols1: &vols-1
    volumes:
        - /home/:/home/

services:
    app1:
        <<: *vols-1
    app2:
        <<: *vols-1
```

To view the resulting config:

```
docker compose config
```